# Python Iterate through rows, run and save

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a pandas dataframe where I want to loop over its rows, run and save output, if any error then ingore it and move to next row.

```
import pandas as pd
from nsepy import get_history #can be install by "pip install nsepy"
from datetime import date

data = {'script': ['SBIN = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))',
'SAIL = get_history(symbol="SAIL", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))', 
'20MICRONS = get_history(symbol="20MICRONS", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))',
'RELIANCE = get_history(symbol="RELIANCE", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))']}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I want to run each line one by one
I can do it by

```
#run each row
#1
SBIN = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))
df1.to_csv('SBIN', sep="\t")
#2
SAIL = get_history(symbol="SAIL", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))'
df1.to_csv('SAIL', sep="\t")
#3
20MICRONS = get_history(symbol="20MICRONS", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))
df1.to_csv('20MICRONS', sep="\t")
#4
RELIANCE = get_history(symbol="RELIANCE", start=date(1985,1,1), end=date(2022,1,31))
df1.to_csv('RELIANCE', sep="\t")
```

But it is going to take huge time. so how can it be done by for loop or while loop

Please note I would like to run each row and save the output as a character extracted before = sign of same row for example "SBIN" for first row. In case if there is any error on any line then ignore the error and move to the next line (line 3 is going to return an error which is due to the unavailability of data)

Comment: From a design standpoint it seems _super_ dangerous to just run whatever code is stored in each row of a DataFrame. It'd probably be safer to configure your DataFrame like `df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': ["SBIN"], 'start': [date(1985, 1, 1)], 'end': [date(2022, 1, 31)]})` then loop over each row, passing individual arguments from the DataFrame to the `get_history` function. Which would allow you to avoid running potentially destructive or malicious code.

Comment: @gupta you should rethink your design. you shouldn't execute strings because someone could insert a malicious string into your data and your program would be forced to execute it

Comment: @Corralien Actually I would like to donwload NSE listed companies historical data using one code. SInce I can do it for each line so what I did, I downloaded all NSE companies and then inserted the one line code as prefix and suffix and now want to run it as an individual line in loop and save output o every line. I can easily do it in r so guessing if same can be done in python

Comment: @DerekO Sure Sir, I would look into it

Comment: @HenryEcker Atually I created the dataframe so it is safe

Comment: @HenryEcker Actually I would like to donwload NSE listed companies historical data using one code. SInce I can do it for each line so what I did, I downloaded all NSE companies and then inserted the one line code as prefix and suffix and now want to run it as an individual line in loop and save output o every line. I can easily do it in r so guessing if same can be done in python

Comment: As @HenryEcker suggests, it's dangerous to exec this code. I proposed you a solution with multiple threads. Take care I found multiple issue with nsepy package about connectivity. You need a good internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your process is IO-Bounded, you can use `Threading` to increase the speed.
You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import concurrent.futures

history = {
    "SBIN": {"start": date(2021, 1, 1), "end": date(2022, 1, 31)},
    "SAIL": {"start": date(2021, 1, 1), "end": date(2022, 1, 31)},
    "20MICRONS": {"start": date(2021, 1, 1), "end": date(2022, 1, 31)},
    "RELIANCE": {"start": date(2021, 1, 1), "end": date(2022, 1, 31)},
}


def get_historical_data(symbol, /, **kwds):
    print(symbol)
    df = get_history(symbol, **kwds)
    df.to_csv(f'{symbol}.csv', sep='\t')
    return df


data = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    future_history = [
        executor.submit(get_historical_data, symbol, **data)
        for symbol, data in history.items()
    ]

    data = []
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_history):
        data.append(future.result())
    df = pd.concat(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is working perfectly. One small prob, I see the output of all 4 companies in the console but when I try to save or print df dataframe it only saves or prints one company, rest 3 are missing. Is it possible to append each company output into the same df or save each company output separately? I am new to python so have no idea how to do it. Please help me

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?